# Restructure a matrix (which contains non-symmetrical values) into a lower triangle matrix format

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, igraph

I'm trying to convert a matrix that is symmetrical in column names, to a lower triangle matrix. This is different to regular questions, as my matrix does not have values that are symmetrical, so cleaning out the values in top half does not work. This would need a restructure to the rows and the columns. Here is the matrix.

```
mat_before <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(8L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("Features",                                                                 "Innovation", "KPI", "Knowledge", "Performance", "Presence", 
                                                                               "Trust", "VFM"), c("Features", "Innovation", "KPI", "Knowledge", 
                                                                                                  "Performance", "Presence", "Trust", "VFM")))

> mat_before
            Features Innovation KPI Knowledge Performance Presence Trust VFM
Features           0          0   0         1           1        0     0   0
Innovation         0          0   0         0           0        1     0   0
KPI                0          1   0         0           1        0     1   1
Knowledge          0          0   0         0           0        1     0   0
Performance        0          0   0         1           0        1     0   0
Presence           0          0   0         0           0        0     0   0
Trust              1          0   0         0           0        0     0   0
VFM                0          1   0         0           0        0     0   0
```

This is the desired result after it's been restructured (to this lower triangle matrix format).

```
> matrix_result 
            Presence Knowledge Performance Innovation Features Trust VFM KPI
Presence           0         0           0          0        0     0   0   0
Knowledge          1         0           0          0        0     0   0   0
Performance        1         1           0          0        0     0   0   0
Innovation         1         0           0          0        0     0   0   0
Features           0         1           1          0        0     0   0   0
Trust              0         0           0          0        1     0   0   0
VFM                0         0           0          1        0     0   0   0
KPI                0         0           1          1        0     1   1   0
```

If you have any hints or tips that would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: I'd also need this code to be replicable to any matrix, which may be symmetrical in dimension, but different in size and column names.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, shouldn't "Features" and "Innovation" switch places in your expected result? And why "Trust" before "VFM"?

Comment: if you notice, the desired result, all the columns and rows move, but stay symmetrical columns,  but the value of 1 is still consistent to where they are previous. e.g. row KPI, column innovation has value 1, in both original matrix and desired matrix. The desired result is now a lower triangle matrix.

Comment: Sure, that's possible. It's a symmetrical reorder of columns and rows. Just the order of Items is what I'm not sure about. If you look at e.g. "Trust" and  "VFM" in your expected result, they are identical. So the order could also be "VFM" "Trust"?

Comment: Imagine I didn't provide the desired result, how would you write code to automatically get there? to restructure the columns and rows to get a lower triangle matrix.

Comment: Maybe `mat_before[order(colSums(mat_before), decreasing=T),order(colSums(mat_before), decreasing=T)]`. Doesn't have the exact order of rows/cols, but is a lower triangle.

Comment: By "symmetrical in column names", do you mean the `i`th column name should also be the `i`th row name after the permutation?

Comment: Going through many of these, this method doesn't work for all situations. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the row/column sums won't work in general:

```
set.seed(1024646989L)
m <- matrix(0L, 10, 10, 0, rep(list(LETTERS[1:10]), 2))
tri <- lower.tri(m)
m[tri] <- sample(0:1, sum(tri), 1)
s <- order(-colSums(m))
m[s, s]
#>   A C F B E D G H I J
#> A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> C 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> F 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> D 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> G 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> H 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
#> I 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> J 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

(Notice `m["F", "B"]` is in the upper triangle.)

However, the adjacency matrix of a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) is triangular when it is [sorted topologically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). We can do this with `igraph::topo_sort`:

```
library(igraph)

s <- rev(topo_sort(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m)))
m[s, s]
#>   A C B F E D G I H J
#> A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> C 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> F 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> D 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> G 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#> I 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> H 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
#> J 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: So far I'm finding solution works consistently for all situations. Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't get your question with misunderstandings, probably you can use the following `igraph` approach

```
mat_before %>%
    graph_from_adjacency_matrix("undirected") %>%
    as_adjacency_matrix(sparse = FALSE) %>%
    `*`(lower.tri(.))
```

which gives

```
            Features Innovation KPI Knowledge Performance Presence Trust VFM
Features           0          0   0         0           0        0     0   0
Innovation         0          0   0         0           0        0     0   0
KPI                0          1   0         0           0        0     0   0
Knowledge          1          0   0         0           0        0     0   0
Performance        1          0   1         1           0        0     0   0
Presence           0          1   0         1           1        0     0   0
Trust              1          0   1         0           0        0     0   0
VFM                0          1   1         0           0        0     0   0
```

Comment: this doesn't work, if you see the row with "Presence" in the original. It should have zeros all the way across. Reference values should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe seems related to the Dulmage-Mendelsohn factorization, which is available in both [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dmperm.html) and [R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dmperm.html) (in package **Matrix**) as `dmperm`:

```r
> library(Matrix)
> dm <- dmperm(mat_before)
> mat_before[dm$p, dm$q]
            KPI VFM Trust Features Innovation Performance Knowledge Presence
KPI           0   1     1        0          1           1         0        0
Trust         0   0     0        1          0           0         0        0
VFM           0   0     0        0          1           0         0        0
Features      0   0     0        0          0           1         1        0
Performance   0   0     0        0          0           0         1        1
Innovation    0   0     0        0          0           0         0        1
Knowledge     0   0     0        0          0           0         0        1
Presence      0   0     0        0          0           0         0        0
```

where clearly the transpose is lower (block) triangular.

Comment: Does that run? I get error message 'could not find function "dmperm" '.

Comment: You may need to update your **Matrix** version.

Comment: But now I see that you desire a symmetric permutation, with `q` constrained to be identical to `p`.  Hence I think that the D-M factorization is the answer to a different question.